# Creating default object from empty value in wp_customize?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have the following code on line 315 and 316 of my theme file customizer.php
For some reason I get error in my error_log file in the root of the installation. Everything seems to work fine though.

```
 $wp_customize->get_panel('widgets')->title = __( 'Widgets' );
 $wp_customize->get_panel('widgets')->priority = 4;
```

This is the error:

> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /wp-content/themes/theme/inc/customizer.php on line 315
>   PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /wp-content/themes/theme/inc/customizer.php on line 316

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: This is a debug message caused by PHP 5.4 on your server and does not indicate a functionality problem with the customizer in most cases. By default, PHP has this set to 0 for production servers on most hosts  (your host should have PHP debugging turned OFF)

Comment: So there is no error here? I can turn off debugging to not fill up the error_log file?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe according to this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress WP_DEBUG_LOG does nothing if WP_DEBUG is set to false?

Comment: So why do I need to set WP_DEBUG_LOG to true? I already have WP_DEBUG set to false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87793/discussion-between-vikrant-zilpe-and-joq3).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, it seems like it returned an array before:

```
$widgets_section = (object) $wp_customize->get_panel( 'widgets' );
$widgets_section->title = __( 'Widgets' );
$widgets_section->priority = 4;
```